# get port without getting ip from regex

Tags: regex

I need to retrieve port number not ip address from log file using regex. my log file has below structure:

```
ip: 123.23.32.1, port: 535
```

if i use `(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3}`, then it retrieves `123 23 32 1` and `535`, i want to retrieve port number, how to do?

i use regex

i use `(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3}`

I expects to retrieve port number only

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each line really looks like this:

```
ip: 123.23.32.1, port: 535
```

### Demo

then you may use the regex pattern `\d+$` to match the port number.  This assumes, of course, that each line would look like this, and would be ending in the port number.

A more general pattern which would be more robust would be to use:

```
port: (\d+)
```

and then access the capture group `(\d+)` after the regex match.

Answer (score 0):

Anchor it to the end of the string with `$` at the end of your pattern.